# Get top 10 list of products based on sales in descending order

Tags: sql

I am interested in getting the top 10 products from the sales table but I am wondering how can it be done using a single query without any limit clause. Here is what I have tried as below.

```
sales( order_id, order_day, customer_id, product_id, quantity, price )

SELECT product_id
  FROM sales
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY SUM( quantity*price ) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: What is wrong with the LIMIT clause? Query looks good on first sight.

Comment: I want to do it without using limit and also I dont want to access table more than once...

Comment: Ok, but only because I'am curious, is there a specific reason, to avoid the LIMIT?

Comment: I was having a ques myself how I can rewrite without using limit clause

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  The question still doesn't make sense.

Comment: The question is simple Gordon.. I would like to implement the problem without using limit clause and not accessing table more than once.

Comment: The question makes no sense. *How can I turn this very simple query into something much more complex by putting ridiculous limitations on how it can be done? And I don't want to do it - please do it for me* is simply wrong. If you have these ridiculous rules about how you want to do it, then figure out how to apply those ridiculous limitations yourself.

Comment: I am not sure whats so wrong in asking questions which are valid Ken... My whole intent is to learn optimal solution rather than just coding a solution for the problem....

Answer (score 0):

I've tried something with "row counter" and HAVING, but with HAVING, the ORDER first make some trouble.

So this bring me to the following:

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT product_id FROM (
    SELECT product_id, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY product_id
    ORDER BY SUM( quantity*price ) DESC) ranked
WHERE rank<11
```

1.) No Limit in sight
2.) and I'am i right, you only access the table sales one time.

Answer (score -1):

simply use OFFSET and FETCH after your order by.
It will do the job for you.

Comment: SELECT product_id
  FROM sales
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY SUM( quantity*price ) DESC

Comment: offset 0 rows
fetch next 10 rows only;

Comment: It's useless to write your answer in comments to your own answer, especially when those comments are different than your answer itself. If you're going to write an answer, do so. Please [edit] the answer and write it there, where it belongs.